# WiFi does not work after Ubuntu update 17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, updates, 17.10, ralink

After updating from 17.04 to 17.10 for some reason, the WiFi adapter drivers were not installed. I tried to install them, but the methods I found do not work. After downloading and unpacking the archive into the `/usr/src` folder, I performed the installation using the command

```
sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force
```

Here's what I got:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch rt3290sta.patch...patching file src/include/os/rt_linux.h
patching file src/Makefile
patching file src/os/linux/config.mk
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.6
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.clean
patching file src/os/linux/pci_main_dev.c
patching file src/os/linux/rt_linux.c
patching file src/tools/Makefile

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=4.13.0-16-generic -C src/ LINUX_SRC=/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/build..............(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rt3290sta: 2.6.0.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

My configuration of WiFi http://paste.ubuntu.com/25891558/

Please, help me to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Did you read `/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log` for more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
sudo dkms remove -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --all
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Reboot

Your device should work fine with the kernel you have with power management disabled for wireless(command #4)
The first 2 commands remove the blacklists on the kernel module and the third command uninstalls the nonworking dkms module

Comment: I know this answer is kinda old now, but can you explanation what these commands do?

Comment: It removes a couple conf files that were added by the user along with uninstalling an added module.  It might not apply to your problem so you may want to ask your own question

Answer (score 0):

There is fork of driver rt3290sta which worked with kernel 4.13.
This really helped me get my wireless driver up and running.
Nothing worked but this did after lot of r&d

If **`make`** fails just edit this file

> vi /home/riz/rt3290sta/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c

and replace on line number 700

> memcpy(extra, addr, i*sizeof(addr[0]));

with

> memcpy(extra, addr, i*sizeof(struct sockaddr));

`

```
git clone https://github.com/pkeeper/rt3290sta.git
cd rt3290sta 
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci
sudo modprobe rt3290sta
```